# mybatis-generator: Create non-java files?

Tags: plugins, generator, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I am using the mybatis-generator in a maven project to generate the Java files for a few tables. At the end of the generation, I would like to generate a few non-java files like properties files and resources. However the default generator allows me to generate only XML and Java files. Is there any way to also get the generator to create sql files, SPI definitions and property files for example?

Looking inside the generator, it seems that the Generated java files and XML files go through some further process(formatting et al). Even if I write a custom plugin, I can generate an XML or an sql file only but not a properties files or an sql file. Even if I did, I cannot get the process to finish because the subsequent steps would fail.

Currently, I am getting over these by creating my own files and writing them thru a custom plugin. However, during the plugin execution, the folder target/generates-sources/mybatis-generator is not created yet. Therefore assuming that location to have already been created is ruled out. On the other hand, if I go ahead and create the folder and its internal META-INF/services folder, I am not sure if this will be overwritten at a later stage. In addition, my plugin does not (by virtue of the way the generator initiates plugins), have access to the project root folder. So that is not an option either.

I neither have access to the ShellCallBack, implying that postponing the file creation to a well defined time-point in the build process is also not possible.

So how do I go about creating the service definitions and the additional resource files?

The last resort is to hard-code the project folder or to pump the project folder through a property. This is coming to my rescue now. But clearly, the generated files are being detected by my git client and I have to clean up these files also despite their being dynamic.

Hints please?

Thanks in advance.
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator currently supports Java, Kotlin, and XML file generation. There is an open feature request to support other file types in plugins. You can follow it here: https://github.com/mybatis/generator/issues/752

Comment: Many thanks. For the framework and for the response.

Let me add that I have moved to the more recent DynamicSql Support and the ease with which the queries can be created is extremely good.

Also note that even in the case of the DynamicSqlSupport, the above requirement continues. I'd like to add the generated files as service providers.